# npm excel-export (Node.js) corrupt files

Tags: node.js, excel, excel-2011

I need to export some data from my node.js application into an excel spreadsheet (for qa purposes). I looked online and found the convenient npm module called "excel-export". I installed it and followed the example that can be found here (https://www.npmjs.org/package/excel-export). It works fine, but I have one issue. When I open the file it says the following:

"Excel could not open filename.xlsx because some content is unreadable. Do you want to open and repair this workbook?"

If I click "Open and Repair", it brings up another dialog that says "Excel repaired or removed unreadable content from this workbook. Do you want to review or save the log file?".

If I click "Save" it brings up the Excel spreadsheet with seemingly no issues, with all my data there and formatted as expected. Anyone have any idea what could be the issue? (For reference, it's Excel for Mac 2011).

Thanks

Comment: Same issue, have you fixed it?

Comment: Same issue too. Have Anyone fixed it?